# postfix reject communication between 2 domains

Tags: postfix

server: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
MTA: postfix 3.3.0

I have 2 local email domains on server, abc.com and xyz.com. I need to reject mail flow between them with reject message. So if someone sends mail from abc.com to xyz.com gets reject message and vice versa. Is it possible? Where to start?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`check_sender_access`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#check_sender_access) to reject (blacklist) or allow (whitelist) specific domains.

Create a new hashmap:

*/etc/postfix/sender_checks*:

```
example.com REJECT Custom reject reason
```

The possible patterns and actions are described in the [access table documentation](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html).

Run postmap on this map

```
postmap /etc/postfix/sender_checks
```

Add the map to `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` in */etc/postfix/main.cf*:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_checks
```

It is up to you to decide, where in the order of your restrictions you want this. I recommend it pretty early. There is no need to do unnecessary checks on mails from domains that are rejected for sure.

Reload or restart postfix.

Comment: Let's clarify: for example if I create such sender_checks file: 
abc.com REJECT
xyz.com REJECT

What will happen if abc.com sends to abc.com? I need only to disable communication between abc.com and xyz.com

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't realize you have those domains on the same server. Then it won't be so easy. Right now I can't think of a possibility to do this just with a postfix configuration. I think you will have to write your own check script.